# Set proxy credentials in ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use a proxy with credentials in ChromeDriver but I don't know how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
ChromeOptions      options = new ChromeOptions();
ProxyManager.Proxy proxy   = proxyManager.GetProxy;

// Configure proxy
Proxy seleniumProxy         = new Proxy();
seleniumProxy.HttpProxy     = proxy.Ip;
seleniumProxy.SslProxy      = proxy.Ip;
seleniumProxy.SocksUserName = proxy.Username;
seleniumProxy.SocksPassword = proxy.Password;

options.Proxy = seleniumProxy;

using (ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, options))
{
    // SOMETHING
}
```

But the program keeps asking me for the credentials (manually).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @Toolkit unfortunately no :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the selenium proxy object supports HTTP proxies with credentials. You configured SocksUsername/pass, which is only used for SOCKS proxies. See [Documentation here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#Proxy_JSON_Object)

Comment: I guess this is it =/ ...that's strange isn't it? That ChromeDriver doesn't support HTTP proxies with credentials.. =(

Comment: It certainly is odd - you could try using IP:port:username:password format for the HTTP proxy despite the documentation stating that isn't supported; it could just be outdated documentation.

Comment: @Crasher did you find a way around this?

Comment: @Arya: not yet :/